# How to combine data providers in testng

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Can some one please let me know how can i combine two data providers together and make it as an single one.

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] Authentication() throws Exception{
        Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/inputs/JoinnowTest.xlsx","Sheet1",4);
        return (testObjArray);
}

@DataProvider
public Object Browsername() throws Exception{
       Object browser = "Iexplore";
       return browser;
}
```

I want to combine this two data providers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create a new class and put both (Object[][] and Object) datastructure together like this:

```java
public class DataProviderContainer {

  private Object[][] auth;
  private Object browser;

  public DataProviderContainer(Object[][] auth, Object browser){
    this.auth= auth;
    this.browser = browser;
  }
  public DataProviderContainer(Object[][] auth){
    this.auth= auth;
  }
  public DataProviderContainer(Object browser){
    this.browser = browser;
  }

  public Object[][] getAuth(){
    return this.auth;
  }

  public Object getBrowser(){
    return this.browser;
  }

  public void setAuth(Object[][] auth){
    this.auth= auth;
  }

  public void setBrowser(Object browser){
    this.browser = browser;
  }


}
```

You can there also include your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

//Using ITestContext object you can combine muliple Dataproviders in one for example

@Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test1");

```
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("Test2");

}
```

//Here t.getName() will return the current test case name to be executed

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dataProvider(ITestContext t) throws Exception{
        Object[][] testObjArray = null;
        if(t.getName().equals("test1"))
        {
            return <AUTHATICATE ARRAY>
        }
        else
        {
            return <BROWSER ARRAY>
        }
}
```